# Functions that can be called only once

Tags: php, function

I've been using the following approach:

```
$foo_called = false;

function foo()
{
    if($foo_called)
    {
        return;
    }

    $foo_called = true;

    // do something.
}
```

I've been wondering if a better / different approaches existed.

Comment: Well, for starters, that won't even do what you want it to do, because `$foo_called` doesn't exist in the function scope. You would need to declare it a global variable inside the function for this approach to work.

Comment: @Hammerite: That's right. I changed the code to address the scope issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just for code clarity, I'd do something like this:

```
function foo()
{
    static $foo_called = false;
    if (!$foo_called) {
        $foo_called = true;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a [static variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static):

```
function foo() {
    static $foo_called = false;
    if ($foo_called) return;

    $foo_called = true;

    // do something.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [singleton pattern](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php)?

from the manual "The Singleton pattern applies to situations in which there needs to be a single instance of a class. The most common example of this is a database connection. Implementing this pattern allows a programmer to make this single instance easily accessible by many other objects."

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of an equally simple one right away. This is simple and reliable. I suppose you forgot the `global` there, but otherwise it should work well.

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot of the context and the reason you want the function to be called only once.

If your function is there to initialize something or start something, you're approach is fine. An other thing you could do, if you are initializing something, is to test if what you want to initialize exist or no.

```
function initSomething() {
    if (isSomethingInit()) return;

    // Init Something
}
```

If you are using those function as callback to something, you can use lambda declaration instead of declaring a function. This will ensure that your function are only called from certain places.

```
function somethingWithCallback($callback) {
    $callback(5);
}

somethingWithCallback(function ($e) {echo $e;});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I like my solution and want to share it.

```
$triggered = false;
$trigger = function($callback)use(&$triggered){
    if(!$triggered){
        $callback();
            $triggered = true;
    }
};

foreach(['Hello','World', 'Wuhuu!'] as $value) {
    $value = ' ' . $value;

    $trigger(function()use(&$value){    // will only run once
        $value = trim($value);
    });

    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your functions in a separate file and include_once the functions.php file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookie to achieve this

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE["cookie_name"])) {
setcookie("cookie_name", "Y", time() +3600, '/');
//php function to run only once
}
```

//+3600 cookie will expire in 1 hr, you can increase or decrease as needed