# How to prevent shortcodes from being executed multiple times

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

It seems shortcodes added to the front page in Wordpress will execute multiple times, possibly this is expected behavior. For example, adding a shortcode called `[myshortcode]` to the front page, and defining it like this in functions.php:

```
function myshortcode()
{ 
     ob_start();

     // This is what really needs to be run only once
     update_my_database();

     return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('myshortcode','myshortcode');
```

WordPress seems to execute this multiple times. Can that be prevented? Or is there another way to execute a function one time and only one time on the WP front page without using a shortcode?

I've tried multiple checks including `in_the_loop()` and `is_singular()` but none seem to work. Also tried adding `remove_shortcode('myshortcode');` within the `myshortcode` function, thinking that might prevent subsequent executions, but that doesn't work either: Tried adding static variables per https://stackoverflow.com/a/3695685/8552218 but doesn't work.

Here's what it looks like with all these approaches, and this still doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
function myshortcode()
{ 
     ob_start();

     if (!is_singular()) return ob_get_clean;
     if (!in_the_loop()) return ob_get_clean;
     if (!is_main_query()) return ob_get_clean;

     static $runonce=false;
     if (!$runonce)
     { 
          $runonce=true;
          return;
     }

     // This is what really needs to be run only once
     update_my_database();
     
     remove_shortcode('myshortcode');

     return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('myshortcode','myshortcode');


function update_my_database()
{
     error_log("Executing...",1,$myemail);
}
```

Comment: so your `update_my_database` is called multiple times - when you load that shortcode on a page ? I think this is something to with `update_my_database` function and not a shortcode issue. I tried and it executed once. Please add `update_my_database` in your question

Comment: ok, I added, for me I receive three emailed copies of "Executing..." from error_log.

Comment: what is `$my_email` ? is there a loop inside there ?

Comment: I think this happens because in some cases `the_content` can be executed multiple times and that's expected behavior with WP (per https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/225722/140624). So in this case every time `the_content` is being executed its re-running the shortcode...  I want to find a way to abort the function if its already been run.

Comment: that's just a placeholder string var I used here to not expose my email address..

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue. I only get email **once** everytime i reload the page with the shortcode

Comment: That makes sense for a fresh install where `the_content` is only being called once. If you want to try and see this happen, try installing the Yoast plugin or any other SEO plugin, it seems they typically take actions that call `the_content` multiple times.