# How to initialize a Tree Data Structure only once on a Sever?

Tags: php, data-structures, server

this is my first time developing a website, and I just have some questions about the way to go forward with achieving some of these requirements I have.

So, I figured that since the website I'm designing is a business website, we want some way to log the transactions. I figured I would go with using a Tree Data Structure (I just call it as a Node Tree) to log all of the transactions on it. I want to make an admin access page that allows the admin to search through the transactions on the Node Tree, but I am stuck on how to keep the Node Tree loaded.

I was wondering if there was a way to write a program that only gets initiated once on a server that can be called to from other files, this way the code doesn't keep running my `transactionTree = new NodeTree();` and erasing all of the stuff added to the tree.

It all sounds confusing I'm sure, since I'm not really the best at wording questions, but what I'm pretty much asking is where should I initiate my `transactionTree = new NodeTree();` so that it doesn't keep being called and clearing the whole tree? I'm fairly new to PHP so I'm not completely sure if there is a function that I don't know about that will load the program only once on a server and I can call to it from other files, or what. Sorry if this is confusing, but any help is very appreciated! If examples of code will help I will post them in an edit.

This is the section where I want to initialize the Data Tree. I only want this code to be called once, so that the code doesn't keep initializing a new `$transactionTree` every time and gets rid of anything on the old `$transactionTree`. Is there a way to achieve that?

```
<?php
   include 'transactionNodeTree.php';
  
   $transactionTree = new NodeTree();

 ?>
```

Comment: Confused as to why you're using a tree structure to log transactions. Are you talking about a persistent store?

Comment: _examples of code will help_ , yes, please post the relevant code snippets to clarify what it is you're stuck on.

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695663/functions-that-can-be-called-only-once)

Comment: @AlexHowansky I got the idea after using a program at my old job at a gas station. I was a manager there and we used this program called "Modisoft" that would track all transactions from the registers and from the gas pumps. We were able to use this to search for specific transactions or transactions of the same item, like pulling up all Marlboro Light Short packs that we sold for the month of July or something like that. I figured I could do something the same way using a data tree. If there is a better way to go about it, I would appreciate the feedback!

Comment: @berend I will try this and let you know if it works! Thank you.